# Add Composer dependency without updating composer.json

Tags: php, plugins, composer-php

I would like to know if it's possible to run

```
composer require "vendor\package"
```

and not have Composer update the primary `composer.json`. For these types of requires I'd like to manage this list independently.

I've tried looking though the documentation but I could not find anything not to 'save' the changes.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this project [composer-merge](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin). I don't think you can do it natively with composer.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i'm looking for.